# Safely reflect a form parameter as a Javascript variable without upsetting Fortify

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fortify

I am analyzing our software using Fortify static code analysis.  Fortify reports that we have a cross site scripting vulnerability (reflected), when I don't think we actually do.

I can either try to argue the point with my customer to convince them that it's safe (something no one wants to do as it requires an audit) or make Fortify happy;

I get a form parameter from the request in ASP.NET, and 'manually' (not using an API) escape it (escape any newlines, \ chars, quotes and remove any script tags).  I then dump it back to the browser as

```
output.Write("var enteredText = \"" + htmlEscape( Form.Params["enteredText"] ) +"\"");
```

Fortify complains unless I do

```
output.Write("var enteredText = \"" + htmlEscape( HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Form.Params["enteredText"]) ) +"\"");
```

but this means that to use the Javascript var 'enteredText' I have to HTML decode it using Javascript, which means another 10k of code on my app (unless I'm wrong).  The whole encoding and decoding of <> and entities in this circumstance is redundant, no?

How can I appease Fortify?

Answer (score 1):

If the application allows arbitrary JavaScript in the enteredText field and has it executed in the browser as JavaScript you indeed have a reflected cross-site-scripting vulnerability, and it is very serious.  Anybody that can cause a user to form post against your application (with, say, a spear phishing attack) can cause all sorts of mayhem against the user.  This is a very straightforward attack.

So, the fix is one of the following

- Reject JavaScript (and HTML and CSS) in this enteredText field. Or, if this breaks your application:
- Review the use case that requires executable code in the enteredText field and whitelist acceptable values.   For JavaScript reject anything that could cause rewriting of the page: event handlers for OnLoad(), document.body.innerHTML (for example), or redirecting the user's browser.
  Also reject anything that could post to remote servers (form, img, css tags for example).  As you imply this could be a lot of code.

This is just a quick example, you'll need to do the research on the type of tags and event handlers that can be used in a cross site scripting attack. If you don't reject those in the enteredText field you'll still have the vulnerability.

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm upvoting it because it's a useful answer, although it doesn't really address what I meant (maybe that's my fault).  My point was that my code sanitizes the output, but Fortify doesn't recognize that (which is not a surprise).  I was hoping to get a way to sanitize that was practical AND that Fortify would recognize.  My customer says anything flagged by Fortify has to go through an audit - and for every release, which is a pain.

Comment: If 'your code sanitizes the out' you mean the htmlEscape() function, escaping doesn't solve cross

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I got a IE8/javascript stack and my anwser was truncated.  What I tried to say is:

If by 'sanitizes the output' you mean the htmlEscape() function, escaping typically does not address cross-site scripting vulnerabilities.  You can really only prevent cross-site scripting by whitelist validation and the Fortify finding is justified.  Now, if htmlEscape does solve the issue (e.g. it does more than escaping the output) you can make sure that Fortify can find that code, or write a 'clense rule' in Fortify so that it ignores vunlerabilities that have this call.

Customers are increasingly having critical software scanned with Fortify and MetaSploit.  I feel your pain.